# Ordenar datos por medio de dos campos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente base de ejemplo:

**Pinned** es el típico "pin de destacado" que puede ser 1 cuando esta activo o 0 desactivado.
**Fecha_Ingreso** esta expresado en linux time, es un entero.

```
*--------*--------*---------------*
| PERSONAS                        |
*--------*--------*---------------*
| Nombre | PINNED | FECHA_INGRESO |
*--------*--------*---------------*
| Angel  |   1    |   1565270107  |  // 2019-08-08T08:15:07
| Pedro  |   0    |   1566306907  |  // 2019-08-20T08:15:07
|  Luis  |   1    |   1565356507  |  // 2019-08-09T08:15:07
| Arturo |   0    |   1565615707  |  // 2019-08-12T08:15:07
| Ramon  |   1    |   1565442907  |  // 2019-08-10T08:15:07
```

Lo que quiero hacer es Ordenarlo principalmente por **PINNED** descendiente, de esta forma me quedaran arriba de los resultados los que tienen el PINNED en 1 (uno), **pero** también requiero ordenarlo a su ve por Fecha_Ingreso, del mas nuevo al mas antiguo (descendiente).

En un inicio realice mi consulta así:

```
select * from PERSONAS order by PINNED DESC, FECHA_INGRESO DESC;
```

Pero solamente me respeta la primer declaración de **PINNED DESC**, ya que solo veo que si esta organizado por PINNED, pero en lo que respecta al FECHA_INGRESO no se esta respetando :(

------ ***Editado 02 Octubre 2019***

Resulta que me ordena la consulta por PINNED e ignora el orden descendiente de FECHA_INGRESO, ya que me aparecen arriba todos los que tiene PINNED=1, pero lo que respecta a FECHA_INGRESO están desordenados, ni están en descendiente ni ascendiente.

Viendo mi lista, me topo con que los NUEVOS registros (con FECHA_INGRESO actual), están ***al final*** de la lista.

Comment: Tu código es correcto según lo que explicas. Tal vez ayudaría más si muestras lo que estás obteniendo actualmente y lo que deseas obtener.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner una captura del resultado de la query para que se vea mejor?

Comment: No veo ningún error en tu consulta, podrías poner el resultado de `select * from PERSONAS`?

Comment: Amigos, resulta que solo se me ordena por PINNED, los que tienen PINNED=1 se visualizan primero, pero ignora el ordenamiento de FECHA_INGRESO, asi que, me quedan al final los "nuevos perfiles" capturados.

Comment: Edite el post principal...

Answer (score 0):

```
select Nombre,pinned , 
       DATEADD(second,FECHA_INGRESO-DATEDIFF(second,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE()), 
       CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime)) 
from PERSONAS order by PINNED DESC,3 ASC
```

con eso debiera bastar.

Comment: El valor entero sigue el mismo orden del valor de fechas. No es necesario hacer ninguna conversión.

Comment: Genial!!! entonces de esa manera el order seria :    order by 2 desc,3 asc, gracias por la acotacion

Comment: También es mala idea usar posiciones de las columnas para definir el orden. Porque al momento de estar haciendo modificaciones, el orden de las columnas puede cambiar. Lo ideal es hacerlo por el nombre o el alias.

Comment: Edite el post principal, mirar porfavor...

Answer (score -1):

se podría solucionar haciendo primero una conversión en la fechas, ya que al parecer lo esta ordenando por valor entero

ejemplo sql server:

```
select * from PERSONAS order by PINNED DESC,DATEADD(second,FECHA_INGRESO-DATEDIFF(second,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE()), CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime)) DESC;
```

otra opcion

```
 SELECT select * from PERSONAS order by PINNED DESC,dateadd(S, FECHA_INGRESO, '1970-01-01 00:00:00') DESC
```

Comment: El valor entero sigue el mismo orden del valor de fechas. No es necesario hacer ninguna conversión.

Comment: Edite el post principal, mirar porfavor...